# How to rotate mapview to moving direction

Tags: android, rotation, android-mapview, forward

I have an android application with google map. I want to rotate the map view after getting the route direction to forward view.. How can I do it?
Picture 1- Backward view ![This is the backward direction view. I need to rotate it to forward][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKkGe.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get bearing from the location, that you received from the `LocationManager` and set it to the `CameraPosition`, like this:

```
    Location location = googleMap.getMyLocation();
    if (location != null) {
        CameraPosition position = CameraPosition.builder()
                .bearing(location.getBearing())
                .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                .zoom(googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)
                .tilt(googleMap.getCameraPosition().tilt)
                .build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));
    }
```

Then your camera will rotate to your direction;

Comment: It means that you location is null, or bearing of your location is the same (as you mentioned backward). Bearing will changed when you will rotate your phone. Do you use `LocationManager` for taking your location ?

Comment: Yes. Is it rotate without moving or while moving? I tested this code without moving the device location.

Comment: I think it should rotate while moving, cause you getting new location with new bearing.